# On standardisation and the use of percentages in linear regression

Tags: interaction, survey, logit, standardization, percentage

After browsing in CV for some answers, I haven't really found what I am looking for.

I am planning to run a regression (on Stata) between the client satisfaction (**Y**) and the provider satisfaction (**X1**) and some socio-demographic variables (age, gender, income). All the data I have comes from surveys. I  combined different questions to create indices.

The indices I obtain have different scales (but are continuous such that I could get 3.45999) so I was wondering: should I standardise my indices or linearly transform them (e.g. to go from 1-7 to 1-5 scale I multiply by 10 and divide by 14)? It seems that the interpretation of the (linear) regression coefficients is much more cryptic when using standardised values.

Another concern I have is the addition of my socio-demographic variables: they are in percentages (e.g. X2 is women and X3 is men and percentages are under the 0.1 form). Also, I am currently using a simple linear regression model. Is it OK to regress the client satisfaction (**Y**) on some percentages? Or should I reconsider my strategy and consider using logit?

Many thanks for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick comments:

- Rescaling your data in some sense doesn't matter.

  - If you multiply $x_1$ by $2$ to get $\tilde{x}_1 = 2x_1$ all that happens when you run linear regression with $\tilde{x}_1$ is that your coefficient estimate $\tilde{b}_1$ will be $\tilde{b}_1 = \frac{1}{2} b_1$ where $b_1$.
- Adding or subtracting a constant from your right hand side variable in some sense doesn't matter either.

  - The coefficient estimates will be the same except for your constant term.
- Whether you standardize or not is basically about whether it's easier to interpret coefficients with respect to the raw variables or standardized variables (it can go either way depending on the problem).
- There's nothing inherently wrong with using a percentage as a right hand side variable.
- Logit models are for when the left hand side variable is binary (i.e. either 0 or 1).

Comment: Thank you, this is really clear! I have a related question when using a % on the right hand side variable: I want to estimate the effect of being a man/woman or white/black/latino, for example, X1 (women %) and X2 (men %) or X1 (white %) X2 (black %) X3 (latino%), but Stata automatically drops one of the variable as if I was using dummies. I am confused - could you help me out?

Comment: Oooh I see - is it because X1 and X2 or X1, X2, X3 add up to 1, hence creating multicollinearity! Would it be the same if I multiplied the % by 100 (so as to get meaningful coefficients)?

Comment: @pdx If x1, x3, and x3 add up to 100%, then they are collinear if your regression has a constant term (which it almost certainly should). Anytime you have that kind of situation, you need to leave one variable out and estimate effects relative to that variable.